# loadeddata in html video triggered too soon

Tags: html, video, dom-events

I'm trying to get a capture of a video to create a thumbnail of it.
For this I need to know when the video is available to get the capture.

I thought `loadeddata` was the event for this, but it is triggered too soon in and the capture results in an empty picture. If I do a `setTimeout` of 100+ it works, so I know the issue is about timing.

Here's the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/estani/ae0ur2kw/28/

Another strange behavior (in Chromium) is that the `readyState` is not always 4 (try running it a second time)

I'm I misunderstanding the event?

**UPDATE**: In Firefox seems to work, is this a Chromium bug?

Comment: the average load time, time when onloaded data is fired on firefox for the given fiddle is 22.2ms and in chrome it's 39.9ms , there is definitely a lag. I don't know your actual requirements, but if there aren't that many videos can you add preload to the video?

Comment: The lag is not the problem, the problem is getting the event that says the data is ready to be read. I thought the `loadeddata` event was meant for this, but it doesn't work (at least for chromium), so therefore my question.